# File upload not working properly on my server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

```
    function upload_cover(){
        $config_cover['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/';
        $config_cover['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|tif';
        get_instance()->load->library('upload', $config_cover);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('myFile') )
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $path = 'img/blog/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
            return $path;
        }
    }
    function upload_file(){
        $config_file['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/';
        $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|txt|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx';
        $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
        if ($_FILES['myDoc']) {
            if($this->upload->do_upload('myDoc'))
            {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $path = 'document/blog/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
                return $path;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is working properly on my computer but when I deploy it on my server only `upload_cover` works, and not `upload_file`. Why?

Comment: Does the upload_path exist? What are the permissions?

Comment: $config_file['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/'; -> $config_file['upload_path'] = 'document/blog/'; both path are exist and the permission is 777

Comment: This is very hard to answer in its current form because most of the logic is hidden in whatever class `$this->upload` is an instance of. Can you post the contents of that class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function upload_file(){
        $config_file['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/';
        $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|txt|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx';

        get_instance()->load->library('upload', $config_file);// try to add this
        $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
        if ($_FILES['myDoc']) {
            if($this->upload->do_upload('myDoc'))
            {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $path = 'document/blog/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
                return $path;
            }
        }
    }
```

...Hope i Help